# zend navigation partial with acl not working

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, acl

I have some trouble with navigation and acl, speaking the permissions are not respected in the menu.
I have an xml config file with the menu. In my bootstrap I initiliaze the menu as following:

```
    protected function _initNavigationXml() {
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml');

    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation)->setAcl($this->_acl)->setRole($this->_auth->getIdentity()->role);
}
```

Due to special format of the menu I have to display it in a partial phtml file, like:

```
<?php
$partial = array('sidemenu.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial();
?>
```

The menu shows well, but the resources are not respected.

Adding following

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu();
```

before $partial, the menu  is correct and the resources are respected.

Any help or further questions will be appreciated ;)
Regards
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

The `renderMenu()` method includes code to check whether the page is visible given the ACL permissions you set.  As far as I can see, if you're using `renderPartial()`, you'll need to handle the ACL checks yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
this does not seem logic but I read that the acl is lost in renderPartial....
Does you have an example on how to do this in a controller as I need the menu only in the dashboard of my application?
Regards

Comment: Probably easiest to look in the code for `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu->renderMenu()`, which calls `_renderMenu()`, which then uses `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract->accept()` to check whether the page should be shown.

Comment: @ChrisAnstey +1 Thank You, Your response helped me a lot, to build renderPartial method with ACLs.